# Get current page URL in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to get the current page URL from my `default_popup` page like this:

```js
chrome.tabs.query({active:true},function(tab){
    url = tab.url;
});
```

And I have registered this `popup.html` page in the `manifest.json` file. Yet
I am getting the error message:

> Uncaught Type Error: Cannot call method 'query' of undefined

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The error you're getting means that the function `query` doesn't exist on the `chrome.tabs` object. Does the part of the extension you're calling this function from have the privileges to access this function? And does your extension have the *tabs* privilege?

Comment: yes i my extension have tabs privilege and i am using above chrome.tabs.query() method inside popup.html page which is registered as default_popup in browser_action: field in manifest.json file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback parameter should specify a function that looks like this:

```
function(array of Tab result){...}
```

Maybe you should write like this

```
url = tab[0].url;
```

Comment: thanks...tab[0] works but i want to ask in the given query active:true   what the other tab array contains means what value does tab[1],tab[2]... will hold ??

Answer (score 2):

Actually the error

```
Uncaught Type Error: Cannot call method 'query' of undefined
```

was because i was running popup.html page separately (separate from extension ) means i was explicitly opening popup.html page in browser to find the error but i forgot that popup.html can use chrome api if it is an extension page and my extension was not showing url because i was usinf tab.url instead of tab[0].url so [Tom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1313206/tom) suggested right ans.