# Set document title as constant and override dynamic updating by page (e.g. 'Facebook' -> '(1) Facebook') in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, title

I'm building a Chrome extension that hides notifications around your browser. I want document title '(1) Facebook' to go to simply 'Facebook', always. In my Chrome extension content script, I have:

```
if (document.title.includes("Facebook")) {
    document.title = "Facebook";
}
```

This doesn't work because `document.title` is being dynamically set by the page:

- when document title first loads (which is also when my content script runs), it shows 'Facebook'
- Facebook page continues to load and document title is set to '(1) Facebook'
- at point that new notification is received (e.g. you're on the page and receive a message) document title is again set - to '(X) Facebook' where X is the new total number of notifications

How can I use my content script to override dynamic updating of the document title in the most efficient way, and set my document title to just 'Facebook' without it ever changing? I could do a `setInterval` with the above function but it seems a bit heavy. I'm hoping to figure out a method that works for other sites as well (Gmail, Twitter, etc.).

Comment: [This answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22989490/934239) isn't a duplicate but contains most of what's needed to make it work.

Comment: Actually now that I re-read the question, it IS a duplicate. If you run into specific implementation questions, feel free to make a new question.

Comment: You can freeze the title in a [DOM-injected script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9515704) via  `Object.defineProperty(document, 'title', {value: document.title})`. The only problem left is to detect user-invoked (intended) page navigation which is shown in the duplicate post.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Xan, greatly appreciate it! Apologies for not finding your question when I searched for answers before writing this one, I had a good look around but missed it. Look forward to implementing. And wOxxOm, thanks too, I will try that as well.